# Flatten a json object in search query elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

In my search query the output as follows:

```
hits" : [
  {
    "_index" : "77",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "b5e790c1-5612-42c3-9289-67d5d2d0fdf7",
    "_score" : null,
    "_source" : {
      "[ReferenceNo]" : 12
      "[Business Unit]" : {
        "[ID]" : 4659,
        "RefCode" : "1_qa1",
        "Code" : "qa1"
     }
}
```

However, I want it to be returned like below:

```
hits" : [
  {
    "_index" : "77",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "b5e790c1-5612-42c3-9289-67d5d2d0fdf7",
    "_score" : null,
    "_source" : {
      "[ReferenceNo]" : 12
      "[Business Unit]" : "qa1"
     }
}
```

What happens is for the [Business Unit] field I don't want to return the json object instead just extract the "Code" field.

Thanks

Comment: What is the DSL or mapping? Field source is the origin text.

Answer (score 0):

Before answering this question, I have suggestion to remove brackets `[ ]` from field name. Just do it before indexing into elasticsearch, because due to this you will face lot of issue while querying elasticsearch.

First option you can use it, source filtering in your query as shown below. This will be easy and it will not impact performance as well:

```json
{
  "_source": [
    "ReferenceNo",
    "BusinessUnit.Code"
  ],
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}
```

Output for above option:

```json
{
        "_index": "index",
        "_id": "us7-8IEBk8SycbzeQ81M",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "BusinessUnit": {
            "Code": "qa1"
          },
          "ReferenceNo": 12
        }
      }
```

Another option you can try is [Scripted Field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting-using.html), but make sure about performance:

```json
{
  "_source": {
    "excludes": "BusinessUnit"
  },
  "script_fields": {
    "b_unit": {
      "script": {
        "source": "doc['BusinessUnit.Code.keyword']"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Response for above query:

```json
{
        "_index": "index",
        "_id": "us7-8IEBk8SycbzeQ81M",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "ReferenceNo": 12
        },
        "fields": {
          "b_unit": [
            "qa1"
          ]
        }
      }
```